# getting warning from google when trying to send verification mail

Tags: java, jsp, gmail, warnings, jakarta-mail

I am sending a verification mail to the user who signup in my site.That mail contains an url like this:

> 117.254.240.197:9090/signup.jsp?code=KtjZ8XSSbYzPyis2DrnKuVTQhWS6rx3Cqp1C5Epl20wSWgSIMOB6m7eweGtoTZ02

Here i am sending a random string through url rewriting to verify the email id. but google is giving waring to the receiver.

**Waring is:** `Be careful with this message.It contains content that's typically used to steal personal information.`
how to avoid it or perform the same task without using url.

Comment: Maybe because you're using an IP address instead of a host name?

Comment: are you sure it is because of ip address?

Comment: No, that's why I phrased it as a question instead of a statement.  Did you try it with a hostname?  It doesn't even have to be **your** hostname for testing, you just need to see if you get a warning when receiving it.

Answer (score 1):

This question on ServerFault has a lot of info that might help you: https://serverfault.com/questions/397097/gmail-suspects-confirmation-email-in-stealing-personal-information

Bottom line is, avoid just sending a link, avoid using the word "link" (as Gmail filters understand it as a spammy word). Provide information about your service and about the email being sent: who are you, what's your website, why is the user getting this email, how to unsubscribe, etc.